# How to Check URL Path Of Images

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Suppose I have an Image located at **“C:\A\mah”** Or **“E:\A\mah”** my question is can I check the URL Path of such an image?  If yes then how?  Which will lots help me to put right URL  path in my Asp.Net Web Application.

Comment: If you use app relative paths, you should be fine. E.g. `@Url.Content("~/content/path/to/your/image.png")`

Answer (score 1):

If those images are not within your project folder, you may need to create a virtual folder (say myImages) and then access images.

```
@Url.Content("~/myImages/imgName.ext")
```

Otherwise you could use

```
@Url.Content("~/path_relative_to_main_folder/imgName.ext")
```

Comment: for virtual folder/directories there should be IIS installed. But there is no IIS Installed in my System.

Comment: Try this: `project properties > Web > Server Section > Virtual path`. I haven't tried this before without IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Never use exact locations. It'll give you a headache. Instead, put a folder in your site's directory somewhere and then reference it with relative paths. For example:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/ABC.png")" />
```

This means it is looking for the Images folder in your project's root directory.

Comment: site's Directory means where?. VS installed at E:\ Drives so do u mean to put images folder to E:\Drives?.